# Docker: readonly filesystem error

Tags: docker, filesystems, reset, readonly

I am required to a create container (docker run), run an application like gams and then destroy the container. for a load test I repeat this a 1000 times. by the end of this test, RHEL7 complains about a 'readonly filesystem' or 'segmentation fault' on ls. the only solution thus far is a disk reset. tried increasing the ulimit. tried resetting $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.none worked.

what could be a good diagnosis?

Solutions so far:
upgraded from docker 1.12.6 to 17.x
set the interval to 5min between runs

no disk reset has been experienced so far after implementing the above two solutions, waiting for the next test to complete to confirm

**Update**

Issue cropped again when copying files from the master node to compute node through java code: "bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file system"

Comment: Do you mean that this issue happens inside a container or is this a symptom of the host? Can you also give some more information such as the output of `dmesg`, the Docker version, and a way someone else might be able to reproduce the test?

Comment: there is a filesystem mapping between container and host - likely symptom of host affected by the container. just got the disk reset and was able to login. dmesg does not seem to have any timestamp. what parts of it should i copy - does it get appended or rewritten after each reboot? Docker version 1.12.6, build 96d83a5/1.12.6.

Comment: That's an outdated version of Docker, which is now on 17.05 for Community Edition, or 17.03 for Enterprise Edition. There's more information on [Docker's site](https://www.docker.com/get-docker).

Comment: I thought 1 was some kind of a prefix with 12 being the major version. Anyways, will install the most recent stable one and try again. Will get back soon

Comment: I had a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871619/docker-for-mac-file-system-became-read-only-which-breaks-almost-all-features-o) and could fix it by restarting docker.